# How to insert a value to MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, text

I have do some calculation in C# and i want insert that value to MySql database. Example totalPrice= Price1+Price2; I want pass the totalPrice into my table. How to do that?

Comment: You pass it as a parameter in your INSERT statement.

Comment: ya...i want pass it as decimal. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an `INSERT` statement.  It's probably best to use parameterized queries rather than just an `INSERT` command.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
string sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable (TotalPrice) VALUES (@TotalPrice)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", totalPrice);
```

Then remember to execute your query.  `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`;

Comment: +1 for parameterized queries. Can't be stressed too much to use 'em!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework...

```
yourTable obj = new yourTable();
obj.name = "name";
obj.created = DateTime.Now;
etc.......
ctx.yourTable.Add(obj);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Insert intoy YourTable values etc..");
```